# Problem with a infrared integrated transistor IS1U621

Tags: transistors, infrared

Hi I'm working on a project in witch I need to use the IS1U621, the circuit implemented is:

[image: Circuit Used for the IS1U621]

but no matter what I'm always getting voltages over 3v on the output, anyone has a tested circuit that I can use??

PD: The drawing has a mistake in the ground and Vcc pins but I have corrected it on the protoboard implementation. That's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are smoothing the output rather aggressively with that 47 microfarad capacitor. The IS1U621 is a high frequency remote control receiver, designed to receive pulses at a frequency around 38kHz. That capacitor is effectively a short circuit at that frequency.
Try removing it, or better yet, connecting it's negative end to the negative supply rail so that it acts as a smoothing capacitor for the power supply. The circuit does require a capacitor in your original position, but it's value should be 1nF.

Also, the +5V should be connected via a 47 ohm resistor, not directly.

By the way, the chip will ignore any slow signals at low frequency. It does this to avoid interference from fluorescent lights etc. You will need a high frequency source, such as a remote control transmitter to test it.